# Can EF Core Order By an non selected column (EF Core Net 5)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In SQL Server one can order a query by a column that is not in the list of columns selected.

Example:

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName
FROM Members
ORDER BY CreatedDate
```

From what I can see this cannot be done with Entity Framework Core 5 as it only allows fields from the selection in `.OrderBy`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Just put OrderBy before Select.  After Select you've changed the type, and downstream operators can only see what you've `Select`ed.

SQL actually messed up in its syntax.  The logical order of query processing is FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, SELECT.  SQL put SELECT first, which is a constant source of errors and difficulty for editing tools.

Comment: Great, feels a bit alien but it works perfectly.